# assert.h not found when including bits/stdc++.h

Tags: xcode, gcc

Yesterday I upgraded my Command Line Tools to version 14.2, and my macOS version to Ventura 13.1.

When I tried to include `bits/stdc++.h` inside a C++ file and compile it, it gave me this error:

```
fatal error: assert.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <assert.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

The error clearly seems to originate from the missing `assert.h` file (along with some others, such as `ctype.h`).

I checked my `/usr/include` directory, and it does appear that the assert.h file does not exist.

I am using g++12 which I installed from homebrew. I tried reinstalling g++ and command line tools, but that did not help. Also, before upgrading my command line tools, everything worked fine. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't even have `/usr/include` on Ventura. Running `locate /assert.h` gives me a long list of hits, both in `/Applications/Xcode.app` and in `/Library/Developer`. Do you see `assert.h` there?

Comment: Who advised you to use `bits/stdc++.h` in the first place? Surely that must lead to more breakage than this?

Comment: Note that `bits/stdc++.h` is gcc-only. As in "GNU GCC", neither "Apple Clang posing as `gcc`/`g++`", nor "LLVM Clang from Homebrew". More specifically, it's libstdc++ only (GNU implementation of the standard C++ library), not libc++.

Answer (score 3):

g++ worked fine again after a while, without me doing anything; this is definitely weird. I did not restart the computer or change any settings.

I've also had this strange error happen to me a few times before (each time after upgrading my OS or Xcode), where the issue just seemed to disappear each time. This might be a minor bug in the Command Line tools.